# Reload nested data in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, animated

I do not manage to update a bar-chart with nested data in D3.js with new data.

I have nested data of the form:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[6,5,4,3,2,1]];
```

I managed to visualize the data by first appending a group for every subarray.
In the groups I then add the arrays as data (simplified):

```
function createGraph(l, svg){
  var g = svg.selectAll("g")  
    .data(l)
    .enter().append("g");  

  var rect = g.selectAll("rect)  
    .data(function(d){return d;})  
    .enter().append("rect")
    . ...
}
```

However, when call the function again with different data, nothing happens.

It seems like in the second row, the rects do not get updated.

I have created a full example over at jsBin: http://jsbin.com/UfeCaGe/1/edit?js,output

Comment: You aren't handling the update and exit selections of the `g` elements. Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsbin.com/akoLUNo/1/edit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more explanation of Lars' bug-catch, since I'd already started playing around...

The key was in this section of the code:

```
  var group = svg.selectAll("g")  
    .data(l)
    .enter().append("g");
```

The variable `group` is assigned the *enter* selection, not the raw selection.  Then in the next line:

```
var bar = group.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d){
            return d;
        });
```

You end up defining `bar` as only the rectangles that are children of just-entered groups.  So even though you were handling update correctly for the rectangles, that whole section of code wasn't even running.  You need to save the group selection before branching the chain to deal with entering groups:

```
var group = chart.selectAll("g")
        .data(dt);

group.enter().append("g");

var bar = group.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d){
            return d;
        });
```

Also, you're missing a `j` in your function declaration in your update.  And you can reduce code duplication by putting your rectangle update code *after* your rectangle enter code, and then any attributes that get set in the update don't have to be specified for enter.  (Some older examples don't use this pattern, because the original versions of d3 didn't automatically transfer newly-entered elements to the main selection.)

```
// enter
bar.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("fill", function(d,i,j){
        return colors(j);})
    .attr("height", 0);

// update
bar.attr("transform", function(d, i, j) {
        x = "translate("+(i*2.2*w+j*w)+",0)";
        return x; })
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", function(d){return d*10;});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. Again I leave stack overflow with new conceptual insights! :)

Comment: You were talking about the missing <code>j</code>, where can I find documentation about the full set of parameter this accessor functions can take?

Comment: That's a good question -- the ability to use a nested index is a bit of a hidden feature, not currently mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-attr); I'm not sure when it was added, but there are some [recent issue fixes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/search?q=group+index&type=Issues) for specific functions where it wasn't being passed properly.  Anyway: **The parameters available to most callback functions are (in order) the data object, the index within the group, and the group's index (usually `d,i,j`).  The node is also available as `this`.**